# AMPscript ContentBlockByName for shared content

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

What is the syntax to use the ContentBlockByName function with shared content. I am getting errors when trying the following:

```
%%=ContentBlockByName("Shared Content\MyContentBlock")=%%
%%=ContentBlockByName("Shared\MyContentBlock")=%%
%%=ContentBlockByName("\MyContentBlock")=%%
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just test this and it works with `%%=contentblockbyname("Shared Content\sharedblock")=%%`

You can also use the browse function:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @EazyE! I think I figured it out. Just sharing content does not put it into the Shared Content folder - it has to specifically be moved there.